# How to use '=' as an argument separator using argparse Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, argument-passing

I want to use '=' as  argument separator and didn't get any option in library documentation. So, '=' supported as a argument separator/deliminator by argparse.

```
class Parse:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("script_config",help="Script Config File")
        parser.add_argument("devices",help="devices")
        parser.add_argument("log_file",help="log_file")
        parser.add_argument("result_file",help="result_file")
        parser.add_argument("testbed_file",help="testbed_file")
        parser.add_argument("runtime",help="Just Runetime")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print pprint.pprint(args)

a=Parse()
```

Output to above code, Here I got runtime as `runtime=10`.

```
 root@ip-:~/cloudzelera/$ python  ../lib/TestsuiteOption.py /tmp/abc.conf qa05__lnx1__i-12b651ea /tmp/123.suite /tmp/result.tmp /tmp/config runtime=10
Namespace(devices='qa05__lnx1__i-12b651ea', log_file='/tmp/123.suite', result_file='/tmp/result.tmp', runtime='runtime=10', script_config='/tmp/abc.conf', testbed_file='/tmp/config')
None
```

Comment: So... Could you post a code that could be just copy pasted so we can execute it?-

Answer (score 1):

`runtime` is not an optional argument, it is a *required, positional* argument. As such you'd never use the name on the command line:

```
TestsuiteOption.py /tmp/abc.conf qa05__lnx1__i-12b651ea /tmp/123.suite /tmp/result.tmp /tmp/config 10
```

If you want `runtime` to be optional, start the option with two dashes (for a long name):

```
parser.add_argument("--runtime", help="Just Runtime")
```

and use the same on the command line:

```
TestsuiteOption.py /tmp/abc.conf --runtime=10 qa05__lnx1__i-12b651ea /tmp/123.suite /tmp/result.tmp /tmp/config
```

Now the option can be used anywhere on the command line, including at the start.

Note that `argparse` uses the UNIX convention of command line arguments, where optional arguments start with `-` for short 1-character arguments, `--` for long arguments. It is not suitable for other conventions.

Comment: I cannot add prefix  '--' in runtime , So I need to use runtime=10 only.

Comment: @user87005: then `argparse` cannot help you. You'll have to write your own command line parser.

Comment: I am already having my own parser(ugly sys.argv parser), Now need to add some command line option, So I am planning to migrate to python's best argument parser. 
{
 106 # Read sys.args
 108 __script_config__ = sys.argv[1]
 109 __devices__     = sys.argv[2]
 110 __log_file__    = sys.argv[3]
 111 __result_file__ = sys.argv[4]
 112 __testbed_file__ = sys.argv[5]
}

Comment: `argparse` uses the UNIX convention of command line arguments, where optional arguments start with `-` for short 1-character arguments, `--` for long arguments. It is not suitable for other conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that what you have specified is not compliant with the Unix argument parsing conventions, why have another line at the end where you would do:

```
args.runtime = args.runtime.split('=')[1]
```